# Why does the decimal number not become binary in this loop?

Tags: c++

Why in this loop where the value of the counter is constantly changing, the decimal is not converted to binary and numbers are displayed randomly?

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
int counter = 1, number, digit, result = 0;
cout << "Decimal\t\tBinary\t\t\tOctal\tHexadecimal\n";
for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i++)
{
    cout << dec << i << "\t";

    number = i;
    do
    {
        digit = number % 2;
        number /= 2;
        result = result + counter * digit;
        counter *= 10;
    } while (number != 0);

    cout << result << "\t";
    cout << oct << i << "\t" << hex << i;
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're reusing `result` and `counter` without resetting them. You should declare and initialize them in the loop instead.

Comment: Note that `int` has likely only 10 decimal digits. Your code thus won't work for inputs larger than 2047.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you so much...It completely fixed

Comment: @DanielLangr Yeah...I didn't notice that...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, the `result` is an `int` so the values will be incremented to each other like this 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 which would result in an output of 2. This can be solved by setting the result to be of type `string`.

Second issue is that you don't reset the values every time. So, this will continue to increase as the time goes on and you need to reset the values inside the loop.

Comment: Doing only the second part is what probably solves OPs immediate problem.The first part I consider "advanced". But you do have my upvote. Thanks for getting this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hey! Thank you so much for your attention to my problem. I've thought about it and now I understand first part. Than you so much again.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as true and although it's not preferred to say it, but glad you got the answer :")

Answer (score 0):

You can conveniently convert and print your numbers from `decimal`to `binary`using the following method

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int decimalToBinary(int N)
{

    // To store the binary number
    unsigned long long int binaryNumber = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (N != 0) {
        int rem = N % 2;
        unsigned long long int c = pow(10, counter);
        binaryNumber += rem * c;
        N /= 2;

        // Count used to store exponent value
        counter++;
    }
    return binaryNumber;
}

int main()
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Decimal=" << i << " " << "Binary=" << " " << decimalToBinary(i) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because I'm a beginner , I have not much information about function but I think now I can try to learn it by this method...thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: `pow(10, counter)` let the magic of rounding floats do its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables at the narrowest scope where they are needed, and initialise them in the declaration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Decimal\tBinary\t\tOctal\tHexadecimal\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        int result = 0;
    
        for (int number = i; number != 0; number /= 2)
        {
            int digit = number % 2;
            result += (counter * digit);
            counter *= 10;
        }
    
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') 
                  << std::setw(3) << std::dec << i << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(8) << result << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(3) << std::oct << i << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(2) << std::hex << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, there is [an easier way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to get a string of the binary representation of an `int`.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Decimal\tBinary\t\tOctal\tHexadecimal\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') 
                  << std::setw(3) << std::dec << i << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(8) << std::bitset<8>(i).to_string() << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(3) << std::oct << i << "\t" 
                  << std::setw(2) << std::hex << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought that I should initialize counter and result out of loop because I imagined It does not matter where the value is . Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: @daryaamimnezhadasl as you can see, it does. Don't try to by-hand micro-optimise your code if you don't understand exactly what it does.

Comment: Hi again. Yes I should try to write my own code with understandable method for myself. Thank you a lot for taking the time for me. 

Answer (score 0):

First of all conversion integer to another integer which after printing as decimal will look like a binary number is insane approach.

It is more reasonable to create function which will covert integer into a text representation of this number in binary base.

```cpp
std::string to_bin_string(int x) {
    if (!x) return "0";
    std::string s;
    while (x) {
        s += static_cast<char>(((x & 1) == 1) ? '1' : '0');
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return { s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nv7zddnEc

There are better ways to do it, but this should be more clear to you.

Comment: Yeah! you're correct. I thought that my code was so logical but it is not. I'm a beginner and I've tried to reform my knowledge. And your method is clear to me. Thank you so much for your attention and write a new code with new method for me

Comment: note there is a bug in this code for negative values!

Comment: Yeah. I guess it only accepts positive values. Thanks for the reminder